# How to Add the row in wpf datagrid in codebehind as datagrid is binded using Xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid

I am using a Xml file to load the Wpf Datagrid using following code

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="FilterData" 
        Source="E:/WPF12/Main27-02-15/IntelligraphicsSniffer24-2-15/Intelligraphics Sniffer/Resources/XMLFile2.xml" XPath="NewDataSet"/>
</Window.Resources>


    <DataGrid x:Name="AddFilterDataGrid" Height="220" GridLinesVisibility="None"  DataContext="{StaticResource FilterData }" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Filter}" >


                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="Name" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=name}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="filter0" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=filter0}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="filter1" 
                Binding="{Binding XPath=filter1}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>
```

sample xml file is:

```html
<NewDataSet>
  <Filter>
    <name>one</name>
    <filter0>12</filter0>
    <filter1>15</filter1>
  </Filter>
  <Filter>
    <name>sathish </name>
    <filter0>999</filter0>
    <filter1>robo</filter1>
  </Filter>
  </NewDataSet>
```

once the form loaded, the wpf datagrid is loading with xml file. it is working fine. but my requirement is to add the rows to the datagrid in code once a button clicked.

I wrote the code for button click event as follows

```
  public void Addfilterrow(string filname,string comments,string src,string dst)
    {
        AddFilterDataGrid.Items.Add(new AddfilterRow() { filtername = filname, filter0 = parentWindow.filterarr[0]});
    }
```

the class AddfilterRow is :

```
  public class AddfilterRow
    {
        public string filtername { get; set; }
        public UInt16 filter0 { get; set; }
        public UInt16 filter1 { get; set; }  }
```

if I use this code I am getting an exception like this "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead"

could suggest me  a solution?

thank you ,
sathish.

Comment: Exception is actually quite explanatory itself. You use `ItemsSource` binding, therefore you can't modify `Items` collection directly. Take `ItemsSource` and add items there instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Addfilterrow(string filname,string comments,string src,string dst)
{
    AddFilterDataGrid.Items.Add(new AddfilterRow() { filtername = filname, filter0 = parentWindow.filterarr[0]});
}
```

According to microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.items(v=vs.110).aspx), Items is a ReadOnly Property. You should have used ItemsSource instead.

**[EDIT]** Answer edited according your comment. ItemsSource is an IEnumerable so either add your item to te collection or create a new collection.

```
public void Addfilterrow(string filname,string comments,string src,string dst)
{
    ICollection<AddFilterRow> items = AddFilterDataGrid.ItemsSource as ICollection<AddFilterRow> ;

    if(items==null)
       return;

    items.Add(new AddfilterRow() { filtername = filname, filter0 = parentWindow.filterarr[0]});
    AddFilterDataGrid.ItemsSource = items
}
```

Comment: if I use above I am getting following error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sniffer.Options.AddfilterRow' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: there is no Add() method to ItemsSource Propert